# Login and Push docker image to (insecure) artifactory docker repo from jenkins pipeline running on k8s

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

**What i want to achieve:**
able to push docker image to (insecure) artifactory docker repo from a jenkins pipeline which is running on kubernetes (jnlp).

**What i am trying:**
I am using kubernetes plugin on jenkins (running on k8s) which is running docker:dind container as slave agent. When i push it fails with certificate error (x509) since its an insecure artifactory repo. Hence To push to insecure artifactory i want to update --insecure-registries in daemon.json of docker client.

But unfortunately, even after updating the daemon.json inside docker:dind it is not taking effect as the docker client used is from underlying node where k8s is running. (minikube in my case) and docker:dind is used as daemon

So i am unable to add my artifactory repo --insecure-registries inside docker client unless i update the daemon.json on the k8s cluster docker client (on minikube)

**What i want to do:**
Hence I want to change docker client from k8s node(minikube) to another docker slave running inside the kubernetes plugin where i can configure daemon.json.
**Can you help me do that ? or please propose a better way to fix this.**

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using docker-in-docker, you can let the jnlp-slave use your host's docker daemon if you mount `/var/run/docker.sock` to it. Then you can edit your host's `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to add your insecure registry.

Assuming your defining your jnlp-slave template in the pipeline, you can do:

````
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  label:
    jenkins: slave
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: registry/jnlp-slave:latest
    volumeMounts:
      - name: docker
        mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
  volumes:
  - name: docker
    hostPath: { path: /var/run/docker.sock }
"""```
````

Comment: I do not want to update host's daemon.json. need an alternative for that. Like changing the client form host to some docker slave so I can update it in the container image.

Comment: Docker-in-docker creates a multitude of issues described in https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/#:~:text=The%20primary%20purpose%20of%20Docker,into%20your%20Jenkins%20container%20instead.